# setting proper cocos2d orientation

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, orientation, launch

In my cocos2d application, inside the applicationDidFinishLaunching method for my app delegate, I set the orientation via [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait] because I really only want portrait. However, Apple rejected my app saying it must support upside down portrait as well.

I'm not certain how I detect this, though. Reading the currentDevice orientation seems to return an unknown orientation, so my questions are twofold:

1) How am I supposed to detect the orientation so I can properly set it to either portrait or upsidedown portrait (where it will stay for good).

2) I suspect I'll have an issue with the splash screen because it's loaded before I reach this point in the delegate. How can I properly detect the orientation so I can set the right splash screen?

Answer (score 5):

I can only edit the codes to fix your first question.. i hope you are using .99.5..

in RootViewController.h, in the function

`-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation`

look for this line:

```
#elif GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
{
return ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape( interfaceOrientation ) );
}
```

change to

```
    return ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait( interfaceOrientation ) );
```

Comment: Actually I was using .99.4. But I gather the proper fix is to update to .99.5. I'm still interested to hear if the splash orientation is still a problem or has a solution, though. Maybe it is just something I see in 99.4.

Comment: The splash screen is still a problem but i dont think apple will reject the app for that.. My company have submitted previous apps with the splash screen facing the other direction but they have been accepted..

Comment: but now it is not supported Landscape, I want to support both portrait and landscape.

Comment: You want a game using cocos2d to support both landscape and portrait?